# Generating a Unique Number by Assigning a Project to an Officer - Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to develop a spreadsheet to keep track of projects assigned to certain project officers and am having some difficulty finding a way to generate a unique number based on a data validation selection.

The final sheet will be more detailed and potentially more complicated than what I am describing here, but I'm starting with the basics and will develop it from there.

Column A - Submission Number - This will be a 3-digit number starting at 001 which will increment for each new project being entered

Column B - Assigned To - This will be a data validation list of names of project officers (e.g. Larry, Roger, Eric, etc.)

Column C - Assignment Number - I want this to auto-fill based on the selection made in Column B. For example the first time Larry is assigned a project this becomes L01, the tenth time Roger is assigned a project this becomes R10, and so on.

Column D - Unique Number - I want this to auto-fill into the following format:
1420/Submission Number/Assignment Number, for example Submission Number 005 assigned to Eric as his second project would output 1420/005/E02.

I would then be able to read the number 1420/005/E02 and know that it was submitted in our 1420 window, was submission number 5, and was Eric's 2nd project.

I have a little experience of using VBA in Outlook but am not sure how to apply it to Excel. I've created a number of spreadsheets in the past using elegant formulae found on these forums so have a decent understanding of how things can work, I'm just not fluent enough to join the formula together myself.

Any thoughts or insights would be greatly welcomed.

Many thanks,

G

P.S. as this is a project for work I will only be available to read and respond to comment during UK office hours

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far? It sounds like this would be possible with some index/match formulas and an `If` statement or two.  Please post what you've tried, what has worked, where you are stuck, etc. so we can help guide you. (Sample table and output is always appreciated as well).

Comment: I would avoid using formulas if you think you'll ever need to move items to different sheets (eg "archiving" old projects etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have column headers in row 1...

In cell C2, enter this formula:

```
=LEFT(B2,1)&TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(B$1:B1,1)=LEFT(B2,1)))+1,"00")
```

In cell D2, enter this formula:

```
=1420&"/"&A2&"/"&C2
```

Copy C2:D2 down as far as needed.

That's it.

No VBA required.